# Am I proving the right thing?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

$Q : $ To find a divisor of $(a + b + c + d)^5 - (a^5 + b^5 + c^5 +d^5)$.

I generalized using multinomial coefficients that :
$(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + ... + x_m)^n - ((x_1)^n + (x_2)^n + (x_3)^n + ... (x_m)^n)$  is always divisible by $n$.

Am I right here ?
As a result of this by putting $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 1..., x_m = 1$, I get $m^n - m$ has to be divisible by n. But that's not correct.
 A counter example is $(m = 2, n = 4)$.

Help me to correctly find the true answer to the generalized formula.

Comment: What you've done should work when $n$ is prime. When $n$ is composite then, as you've seen, the multinomial coefficients aren't always divisible by $n$.

Comment: How did you get that the multinomial coefficients were divisible by $n$? Does your argument work when $n$ is prime?

Comment: @jgon I separated the terms when $k_1 = n, k_2 = n ... k_m = n$ from the multinomial coefficients. And then new conditions on the multinomial coefficients become $k_1 + k_2 + ... + k_m = n$ and $k_1 <= n - 1, k_2 <= n-1, ... k_m <= n-1$.Then I assumed that I can always take a n out from the numberator and that $(n-1)!/(k_1!k_2!...k_m!)$ belongs to I+.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but it only necessarily works in general for primes. By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), you have for any integer $n$ and prime $p$ that

$$n^p \equiv n \pmod{p} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, your expression gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& (a + b + c + d)^5 - (a^5 + b^5 + c^5 +d^5) \\
& \equiv (a + b + c + d) - (a + b + c + d) \\
& \equiv 0 \pmod{5}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

i.e., $5$ is always a divisor.

Comment: Wow I am stunned, looking at this now. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the other answer: there are two other guaranteed divisors, $2$ and $3$.

Observe that mod $3$, we have $0^5 = 0, 1^5 = 1, 2^5 = 2$ and so it is similarly the case that
$$n^5 = n \mod 3$$
and hence your expression is $0$ mod $3$. The same works for $2$.

The above argument works only for $2,3,5$. For take a prime $q$ and suppose our congruence holds,
$$n^5 = n \mod q$$
for all $n \in \mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$. This is a polynomial of degree $5$ and so it has at most $5$ different roots. But $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$ has $q$ elements which are all roots of the above, and so $q\leq 5$ and we have checked that all those cases work.

Also, by considering the examples $1,1,1,1$ and $1,1,2,3$ for $a,b,c,d$ you can see that there are no other guaranteed divisors.